# running mysql_fix_privilege_tables kills my root password

Tags: mysql, macos, scripting

I am learning mysql and ran into a problem with 'mysql.proc' missing when trying to create a stored procedure.  mysql version 5.1.41.

I read that running the script 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables' is supposed to fix the previous error.  I am getting a strange side effect... my root password is no longer good anymore when I run this script and can no longer log into mysql because of this.  the only solution is to remove mysql and start over.  I have done this twice now and have no clue as to why it is affecting my root password.  any clues?

Updated 11/28:  I found it is a bug in workbench with a particular model sync setting.  It is removing the mysql database and for some reason when you do a repair, mysql erases all users.  Kind of a perfect storm kind of thing I think.

Comment: UPDATE** after using the articel from tommieb75,  I found that it didn't remove my root password... it removed root all together.  After getting mysql into safe mode... I typed SELECT user FROM mysql.user; and it returned empty set.  HELP!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this [article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/442) (geared at Debian Linux running mysql) might help you and save you the pain in having to remove mysql and reinstall again. The principal should remain the same as I have noticed this is tagged with macosx.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: This definitely helps... Thx.  Why would I get the mysql.proc error to begin with? any idea?

Comment: Better yet... why would the script change my root password? Thx for the help!

Comment: @sdmiller: Can you show what you were doing exactly at the point prior to this problem? A side note, that script could have a bug in it. Report it to mysql team, as you are running macosx. It will be of help to them! I have never used this script tbh...http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql_fix_privilege_tables this shows the man page for the said script..read what it says about it superseded by a newer script....then again, that script is something you run once against mysql..

Comment: I loaded mysql workbench.  I synced the databases once and then started getting 'missing mysql.proc' error any time I tried to sync or add a stored procedure.  I read online that the mysql.proc error sometimes occurs due to databases not being up to date or something like that and to run the mysql_fix_privilege_tables' script and that should fix it.  After I run the script, I can no longer log into mysql using root and password.  I used link you supplied in order to reset the password and found that root can been removed completely... I have no users in mysql anymore.  Thanks for you help

Comment: @sdmiller: check this and verify you have the right version of mysql...http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,73660,74161#msg-74161. Also...there may be light at the end of the tunnel here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,73660,73660, Look at the last 4 replies in that thread and see if that sheds any light...Hope this helps you. Take care. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I am definitely running mysql 5.1.41, The stored procedures work until I run the sync in mysql workbench. Then I get the mysql.proc error and can't create stored procedures anymore.  It is weird.  THanks for you help!